# Laravel views not functioning

Tags: laravel-4

I have a web application in laravel in `"mysite/admin"`. On login loads view `"views/dashboard/index.blade.php"` correctly , but when I click a link should return  `View::make('dashboard\index.blade')`->with`('general', View::make('dashboard\listoff'));` but

```
InvalidArgumentException View [dashboard\index] not found.
```

The same is working correctly in localhost.

Comment: You don't need to include `.blade`. Just `dashboard\index`

Comment: I would change back slash in view path to forward slash -> `View::make('dashboard/index')` or `View::make('dashboard.index')` (I preffer dot notation, Laravel understand this and resolves correct file) Also, do not pass View at path `dashboard/listoff.blade.php` as `$general` variable, use `@include('dashboard.listoff')` to load that view in `dashboard/view.blade.php` file

Comment: Thanks Andreyco for the reply.The problem was with the backslash. Thanks once again.